# nativescript vue dialogs.confirm - code is not executed inside dialogs

Tags: vue.js, modal-dialog, nativescript, nativescript-vue

i have a method "deleteItem". Inside is a code-block with **dialogs.confirm** and the code (deleting key of array and saving array) will not be executed. console.log is executed and prints "true". Code is working well outside the dialog. Any ideas?

```
var dialogs = require("tns-core-modules/ui/dialogs");
```

...

```
      dialogs.confirm("Delete ?").then(function(result) {

        if (result) {

          console.log("in deleting: " + result);
          // delete item
          this.contacts.splice(this.contacts.indexOf(actItem), 1);

          // add to ASStore as new array
          appSettings.setString("ASStore", JSON.stringify(this.contacts));


        }
      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the context, use arrow functions Or store value of context (`this`) above confirm dialog and use the reference.

```
dialogs.confirm("Delete ?").then((result) => {

        if (result) {

          console.log("in deleting: " + result);
          // delete item
          this.contacts.splice(this.contacts.indexOf(actItem), 1);

          // add to ASStore as new array
          appSettings.setString("ASStore", JSON.stringify(this.contacts));


        }
      });
```